# How to get back to previous state after applying a matrix on a image?

Tags: image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabricjs where I am applying some image filters using their convolute.

But it is very slower on image size more than 200KB.
Hence, I decided to write my own logic to apply filters and then to call canvas.renderAll() to update the canvas from the image canvas.

I am able to apply emboss using kernel 

                   `matrix: [  -2, -1, 0,
                              -1, 1, 1,
                              0, 1, 2 ]`

But How to get back to original state of image ,In other words , do I need to apply any other kernel/matrix?

Comment: You can not reverse a convolution filter. You need to make a copy of the image before you apply the filter.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f6P3R/ , click on the image ,then check/uncheck the checkboxes , it works? I cannot use it because it angs the browser for bigger images

Comment: Yes fabric makes a copy of the image, Mathematically the convolution filter you show above can not be reversed as you can not determine from which pixels each component of the result originated from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all write your own filter class:

```
(function(global) {

  'use strict';

  var fabric  = global.fabric || (global.fabric = { }),
      extend = fabric.util.object.extend;

  fabric.Image.filters.MyFilter = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter, /** @lends fabric.Image.filters.MyFilter.prototype */ {

    /**
     * Filter type
     * @param {String} type
     * @default
     */
    type: 'MyFilter',

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    initialize: function(options) {
      options = options || { };
    },

    /**
     * Applies filter to canvas element
     * @param {Object} canvasEl Canvas element to apply filter to
     */
    applyTo: function(canvasEl) {
      var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d'),
          imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height),
          data = imageData.data,

      for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i += 4) {
        data[i] = 255 - data[i];
        data[i + 1] = 255 - data[i + 1];
        data[i + 2] = 255 - data[i + 2];
      }

      context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    },

    /**
     * Returns object representation of an instance
     * @return {Object} Object representation of an instance
     */
    toObject: function() {
      return extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {

      });
    }
  });

  /**
   * Returns filter instance from an object representation
   * @static
   * @param {Object} object Object to create an instance from
   * @return {fabric.Image.filters.RemoveWhite} Instance of fabric.Image.filters.MyFilter
   */
  fabric.Image.filters.MyFilter.fromObject = function(object) {
    return new fabric.Image.filters.MyFilter(object);
  };

})(typeof exports !== 'undefined' ? exports : this);
```

Second, apply the filter with your normal fabricjs logic:

```
myimage.filters[0] = new fabric.Image.filters.MyFilter;
myimage.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

When you want to go back to normal image do:

```
myimage.filters[0] = null;
myimage.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Some considerations:

1) if the code you posted is your filter, it looks like an invert colors filter available at:

```
fabric.Image.filters.Invert()
```

2) if you really want to invert the formula again, you just need to run the filter again if you want to use a custom function.

if `a = 255 - a`, doing again `a = 255 - a` will revert to a original value.

3) some filter are not invertible, and if they are is better to store a copy of the image other than going back pixel by pixel.

Comment: I am unable to understand your answer. Can you add a fiddle to explain the answer . <br/> Suppose this is the code to modify reference canvas : `     var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, hc.width, hc.height);
         var data = imageData.data;
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
              data[i] = 255 - data[i];
              data[i + 1] = 255 - data[i + 1];
              data[i + 2] = 255 - data[i + 2];
            }
            // overwrite original image
            ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
         canvas.renderAll();`

Comment: i explained better what you could do.